# Didn't find class "androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner" Sentry

Tags: flutter, dart, android-jetpack-compose, sentry

I upgraded the sentry version to 7.11 as I upgraded flutter & intl

the problem is that now my app doesn't start and I get this error:

```
D/Sentry  (23065): Class not available:androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner
D/Sentry  (23065): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner
D/Sentry  (23065):      at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.android.core.LoadClass.loadClass(LoadClass.java:21)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.android.core.LoadClass.isClassAvailable(LoadClass.java:39)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.android.core.LoadClass.isClassAvailable(LoadClass.java:44)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.android.core.AndroidOptionsInitializer.initializeIntegrationsAndProcessors(AndroidOptionsInitializer.java:147)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.android.core.SentryAndroid.lambda$init$1(SentryAndroid.java:127)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.android.core.SentryAndroid$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.configure(Unknown Source:8)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.Sentry.applyOptionsConfiguration(Sentry.java:176)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.Sentry.init(Sentry.java:146)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.android.core.SentryAndroid.init(SentryAndroid.java:89)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.android.core.SentryAndroid.init(SentryAndroid.java:70)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.flutter.SentryFlutterPlugin.initNativeSdk(SentryFlutterPlugin.kt:126)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.sentry.flutter.SentryFlutterPlugin.onMethodCall(SentryFlutterPlugin.kt:57)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:258)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:322)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8176)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
D/Sentry  (23065):      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
D/Sentry  (23065): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.compose.ui.node.Owner" on path: DexPathList
```

anyone has experienced this error or knows what is going on?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the SDK. I opened a ticket with the SDK team: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dart/issues/1704 They'll need more info such as: What version were you on before? Version of Flutter and of Sentry, before and after the upgrade, that is. What device model/version you're testing is also helpful.

Comment: The app actually doesn't crash, the crash was due to something else, but thank you very much for the support!

It's probably just a bug, sentry seem to work fine and the app is unaffected

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, and it was resolved by commenting out

```
debug= kDebugMode
```

```
 await SentryFlutter.init((options) {
    options
      ..dsn = my_url
      //..debug = kDebugMode
      ..tracesSampleRate = 1.0
      ..environment = 'Test';
  }
```